# How to sketch functions in polar and spherical coordinates by hand on paper?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I've been practicing drawing surfaces in different coordinates. I can do the easier ones but no I am completely stuck on the following two:

Say we define spherical coordinates as follows:

[image]

so that $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ and $\phi \in [0,\pi]$.

Then I want to draw (without using software):

$$ \rho = \phi$$

and

$$ \rho = \cos \phi$$

Here is how far I got so far:

Luckily, the angle $\theta$ is free so all we have to do is find the shape in the $xz$-plane and then rotate. So this reduces to drawing in polar coordinates.

Unfortunately, this insight does not help me further since I am equally stuck in only 2 dimensions when it comes to polar coordinates.

For the first one I see that as the angle grows so does the radius but this doesn't help me draw the exact shape. It crosses the $x$ axis at $\pi$ and the $z$ axis at $-2\pi$ but again this doesn't give me the exact shape.

For the other equation I tried to rewrite it:

$\cos \phi = {y\over \rho}$

but I do not see how this will help me draw the function.

> Please could someone help me and explain to me how to draw such
>   functions?

Comment: So you must to think in circles when radious $\rho$ is fixed or lines when the the angle $\theta$ or $\phi$ is fixed in the plane case then in space what figures are most simples?